# How to make 2 event loops work together - Tkinter and PyPS4Controller

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, controller

I am currently on a project where I have to use Tkinter to make a game, and I would like to be able to move stuff on a canvas in Tkinter (like moving a circle with a ps4 controller's joystick for example).
In this project, it is mandatory that I use tkinter to make the UI of the game, so I needed a python module to handle my PS4 controller. I chose to go for [PyPS4Controller](https://pypi.org/project/pyPS4Controller/)

But there are two event loops : `tkinter.mainloop()` from the Tkinter module and `controller.listen()` from the PyPS4Controller module.

I'm really lost. Your help is much appreciated. Thanks ! ;D

Edit:

Further down is the code I came up with to showcase my problem, along with the live result in the console. Even with the pyPS4Controller event loop inside a thread, my program is still stuck, waiting for an input

```
import tkinter as tk
from pyPS4Controller.controller import Controller
import threading

# The list the will contain all events related to the PS4 controller
eventQueue = []

# Function to launch a thread, for appending
# user inputs to the eventQueue
class getPS4Input(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, controller):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.controller = controller

    def start(self):
        # No more visible loop, it is already in controller.listen
        self.controller.listen()

# All events that are related to the controller are handled by
# this class (a pyPS4Controller module specific class)
class MyController(Controller):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        Controller.__init__(self, **kwargs)

    # On the X button is pressed
    def on_R3_right(self, value):
        # Append the new value for the xaxis along with a tag used to 
        # understand what the value is for
        eventQueue.append(('R3_xaxis', value))
      
    # Other events (none here for exemple purposes)

# The object that needs to be moved around
# Here its purpose is to have a way to know if the R3_xaxis value
# has been modified
class ball():
    def __init__(self):
        self.R3_xaxis = 0
    
    def show(self):
        print(self.R3_xaxis)

# The function to be called periodically by tkinter
# to update here just the R3_xaxis, example purposes
def checkEventQueue(ball):
    while (eventQueue != []):
         # Get new events until there is none left
        [eventTag, eventValue] = eventQueue.pop()
        # Update the R3_xaxis value for the object ball
        if (eventTag == 'R3_xaxis'):
            ball.R3_xaxis = eventValue
    # Repeat the check every 200 ms
    root.after(200, lambda:checkEventQueue(ball))

# The controller, view as an object by Python
controller = MyController(interface="/dev/input/js0", connecting_using_ds4drv=False) 

root = tk.Tk()

# A button, just to see if the tkinter loop is running correctly (not stopped)
tk.Button(root, text ="Hello", command=lambda:print("Bouton TK appuyé")).pack()

# Initialize the thread to get user inputs
t = getPS4Input(controller)
t.start()

# Check for user inputs entered in the last 200 ms
root.after(200, lambda:checkEventQueue(ball))

# The Tk event loop
tk.mainloop()
```

Here is the live program result, as you can see, it is waiting for an input (actually for a controller to be connected, but you see my point, I don't want to be stuck here, I want to get to the Tk mainloop)

```
Waiting for interface: /dev/input/js0 to become available . . .
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: use threads, I don't see why wouldn't you be able to always listen for inputs in that case, you should provide a [mre] if you want more specific help tho

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I would love to share a piece of code, but that would be junk. As I explained, I can't make up the how of putting it together in a correct way..

Comment: and we don't understand why because you haven't shown what you did attempt. it should be pretty simple really, something like putting data from the thread when user inputs something (pressing a button for example) in a queue and then in the `tkinter` thread check the queue with `after` "loops" and act accordingly

Comment: Rename `start()` to `run()` inside class `getPS4Input`.